# Reaction with ethyl chloroacetate and potassium carbonate

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am carrying out a reaction using ethyl chloroacetate, potassium carbonate in acetone for a compound containing $\ce{-NH}$ group. So, the substitution will be at $\ce{-NH}$ position.

I have tried stirring at room temperature, but no product obtained.
Refluxing has given a liquid product. Reported product should be white crystals.
Any suggestions for how to get the product?

Comment: What is the nature of the NH you are trying to substitute? You could add a bit of KI to make the iodoacetate in situ, this will be more reactive. Swap acetone for acetonitrile if there is a possibility the NH is reacting with the acetone.

Comment: Your target is a $N$-substituted glysine derivative?

Comment: Are you sure that obtained liquid product is not desired product as liquid? Maybe some solvent is remaining and is preventing crystallization.